# Non Public API usage and access the UDID

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have Problem with IOS App Validation errors: Non Public API usage and access the UDID,
i am not using UDID and also search uniqueIdentifier on the app but i didnt find any.

also i am using the latest version of admob and revmob but when i delete them also the problem is the same .

i open the terminal and paste this to check what is excat problem 
find . | grep -v .svn | grep ".a" | grep -v ".app" | xargs grep uniqueIdentifier

and nothig.

can someone help to point me to the problem .?

Comment: have you tried smth like  find . | grep -v .svn | grep ".a" | grep -v ".app" | xargs grep UDID

Comment: its saying - xargs: grep: Argument list too long

Comment: maybe some other third-party frameworks use uniqueIdentifier ?

Comment: i searched on all the code this - uniqueIdentifier But its was found just on chartboost but i deleted it also . 
On my Code there is - #import "MobClick.h"
But i didnt find nothing on google . ....
but i deleted it ...

Comment: how can i see what is the problem